# Make Report Viewer Scrollable

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm new to the Report Viewer so I need some help because I'm retrieving some information from my data base but they are way to many so the list just goes down which isn't appropriate.

How can I make it scrollable?

What property do i need to add to this

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Width="100%"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding CSS "`style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll`" got this working:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" PageCountMode="Actual"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Regards